# Make parts of textview clickable (not url)

Tags: android, android-layout

i've been struggling for some time now. On an activity in need the text: By clicking Register, I agree to the Terms of service and Privacy policy.
The parts "Terms of service" and "Privacy policy" needs to be clickable. The solutions that i've found, made url's. But i don't need an url to browse to the terms, in need to start the terms activity, or the privacy activity.

Then i've found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9076448/1387161
But the problem here is, they aren't aligned beautifull. What i mean: if there is a phone with a small resolution, i need to set textview1 next to textview2 and textview3 under textview1, with next to it, textview4. But when i use the app on a tablet or a phone with a bigger screen, maybe all of the textviews can stand next to eachother, but the layout stays the same as on aphone's with a small screen =

Textview1 - Textview2
Textview3 - Textview4

One possible solution can be the flowlayout, but i'm getting errors and can't seem to find a good tutorial (for beginners)
[How to use flowlayout (or any custom layout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960201/how-to-use-flowlayout-or-any-custom-layout)

Any ideas are appreciated!

Thx,

Bjorn

Comment: in the xml layout, just add `clickable="true"` then use the `onClick` event like you would a button.

Comment: You say that you don't want to use url,  do you mean you want the visual effet of urls but to open activities. OR do you mean you don't want it to look like urls ?

Comment: I wan't it to look like url's, but start an activity and i don't want to start a browser

Comment: Better try https://github.com/ajaysahani/MultiActionTextView

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView _tv;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );
    String sentence = "this is [part 1 clickable] and [part 2 clickable] and [part 3 clickable]";


   _tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
   _tv.setText(addClickablePart(sentence), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
private SpannableStringBuilder addClickablePart(String str) {
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str);

    int idx1 = str.indexOf("[");
    int idx2 = 0;
    while (idx1 != -1) {
        idx2 = str.indexOf("]", idx1) + 1;

        final String clickString = str.substring(idx1, idx2);
        ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, clickString,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, idx1, idx2, 0);
        idx1 = str.indexOf("[", idx2);
    }

    return ssb;
 }
}
```

Edit

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView _tv;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    _tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView1 );

    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Android is a Software stack");

    ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(), 22, 27, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);//22 to 27 stack is clickable
    ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(), 0, 7, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);//0 to 7 Android is clickable

   _tv.setText(ss);
   _tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
}
class MyClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan{ //clickable span
    public void onClick(View textView) {
    //do something
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
       ds.setColor(Color.GREEN);//set text color 
       ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
    }
}
}
```

More info on ClickableSpan http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html

You can also style the spannable string by making it bold , italics or setting font size.

```
    StyleSpan boldSpan = new StyleSpan( Typeface.ITALIC );
    ss.setSpan( boldSpan, 22, 27, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
    StyleSpan boldSpan1 = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(3f), 0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);//set fontsize
    ss.setSpan( boldSpan1, 0, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );
```

Comment: This is nice, but the brackets are visible for the user. Is there a workaround?

Comment: And if you do not wanna the clicked part  highlighted with a default (Mine is green ) color, try `_tv.setHighlightColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use Raghunandan Answer with a HTML Message do the following
In your Display function

```
public void displayText(String message) {

            chapterTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(message),TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            chapterTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            Spannable clickableMessage = (Spannable) chapterTextView.getText();
            chapterTextView.setText(addClickablePart(clickableMessage), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

The Modified function of addClickablePart

```
private SpannableStringBuilder  addClickablePart(Spannable charSequence) {
        SpannableStringBuilder  ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(charSequence);

        int idx1 = charSequence.toString().indexOf("(");
        int idx2 = 0;
        while (idx1 != -1) {
            idx2 = charSequence.toString().indexOf(")", idx1) + 1;

            final String clickString = charSequence.toString().substring(idx1, idx2);
            ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), clickString,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, idx1, idx2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            idx1 = charSequence.toString().indexOf("(", idx2);
        }

        return ssb;
    }
```

Hope this help someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClickableSpan cs = new ClickableSpan() {  
     @Override 
     public void onClick(View view) {  
        //action stuff here
     }  
};

String text_terms_string = getResources().getString(R.string.register_terms_text);
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(text_terms_string);

int termStart = text_terms_string.indexOf("Terms");
int termStop = termStart + "term".length();

//we set here clickable our text  
ss.setSpan(cs, termStart, termStop, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

//we set here our color i.e. #cccccc in this example I take color from xml  
ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.aquaBlue)),termStart,termStop,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

//we set here text to be bolded    
ss.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD),termStart,termStop,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

//I set here spannable text to my previous declared TextView  
text_terms_link.setText(ss);

//We set here clickable text, this is important !!  
text_terms_link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok so you need to make text view click-able , its simple.
create object of text views and call activity

```
      termnservc =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.srvid);
      termnservc.setOnClickListener(this);
       // use on click method
                    @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                                         
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.srvid:
        Intent termsandcondition=new Intent(this, TermsOfService.class);
        startActivity(termsandcondition);
        break;
                    }
```

}